# Reference for modeling with WinBugs

Tags: self-study, bayesian, modeling, jags, bugs

Does anyone have any good reference for beginners in WinBUGS about modeling?

I already have some familiarity with R, but I had never used R2WinBUGS before. I'm interested in making beta, beta rectangular, and simplex regression models.

Although I have found some ready-made templates codes, it is very difficult without some knowledge to understand how they work and make any kind of adaptation.

I also ask if there are already packages in the R for diagnostics of models made from BUGS, such as residual analysis.

**EDIT:** Can anyone explain to me the difference between WinBUGS and JAGS. I made some research and found it in some R2jags description

> "model.file file containing the model written in BUGS code"

So the model in JAGS is writted in BUGS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although WinBUGS made a monumental contribution and impact, and BUGS is still used by many people, it is IMHO sort of a legacy system, and many people now prefer JAGS. (Or, if you don't mind breaking away from BUGS/JAGS syntax, you can use Stan.)

For resources about BUGS, there is, of course, [The BUGS Book](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-the-bugs-book/). Notice it lists a lot of [resources and references](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-bugs-resources-online/).

Or you could consult the [1st Edition](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/1st-ed-stuff) of Doing Bayesian Data Analysis, but all of its scripts were converted to JAGS. For JAGS, there's the 2nd Edition of [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/).

Comment: Is Stan better than Jags?

Comment: I don't need to know BUGS to write the model to use in JAGS?